# Modifying a threads data from outside the thread

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

How does one modify a threads data from outside a thread?

If a thread is running a function that loops for the runtime of the application, how can its data be set, changed?

How does one call functions which modify a specific threads functions?

Where do these functions belong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage and disadvantage of threads is that they share the memory space with every other thread in the process. You can use any form of data transfer you would use in single threaded applications to pass data betweens segments of you application. However, in a multi-threaded application you must use some type of synchronization to assure data integrity and prevent deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

If the "thread's data" you want to modify from outside is in the form of local variables in a function running in the thread, or thread-specific data created with the `__thread` extension, then the *only* way you can modify them from outside (modulo code with UB that's technically just trashing memory) is by having the thread take the addresses of its variables and store that somewhere where other threads can see it (either in a global variable, or at a location passed in via the thread start function's `void *` argument.

Also note that, as rerun pointed out, you have to use some method of synchronization if multiple threads are accessing the same data. The only standard/portable synchronization methods are the pthread ones: `pthread_mutex_lock` etc., but you can also use assembly or compiler intrinsics (like `__sync_*` in gcc).

Comment: What if there is no other thread or function modifying the same data. I just want to modify some data that is running in the thread. Will it be fine to just modify e.g. a pointer which is declared outside the threaded function and just modify it outside the thread as well. The the thread will read the pointed to data and updating will be fine?

Comment: If one thread reads memory that another thread has modified without an intervening pthread synchronization primitive, the result is *undefined behavior*, per POSIX. Pratically, it's not going to give you nasal demons, but what this means is there's no guarantee about whether your thread will "see" the change made by another thread. On x86 and x86_64, you will see the change, unless the compiler saw that there was no way the variable could be legally modified and optimized out reloading it (`volatile` would fix this). On other archs though, special memory barriers may be needed.